# Paypal transfer one user to another user

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-sandbox, paypal-adaptive-payments

Iam looking to transfer money from one user to another user using paypal ExpressCheckout.

Is it possible to send money to user to user with ExpressCheckout.
its not a marketplace we don't have seller or buyer or merchant.

Am making social networking so that friends can transfer money within my site using paypal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Parallel Payments in Express Checkout without having an adaptive payment application registered. But if you required some chained mechanism, you may need to use Chained Payment in Adaptive payment.